# Etsy's Android Staggered Gridview - drawSelectorOnTop

Tags: android, gridview, staggered-gridview

I'm trying to use Etsy's Staggered Gridview (https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView), and I have it working mostly as expected, except I'm having an issue trying to get the selector to draw on top.

I've tried using mGridView.setDrawSelectorOnTop( true ); and android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" in the layout, but no success yet. Anyone happen to have solved this problem, or know if it's not possible with the library in its current state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Etsy's StaggeredGrid frustratingly doesn't support item selector drawables. To work around this, set the selector on the GridView *item*, not the GridView itself.

In my current project, I wrap the GridView item in a `FrameLayout`, because a FrameLayout has an `android:foreground` attribute:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <!-- Your item layout goes here. -->

</FrameLayout>
```

`?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` gives you the standard blue highlight. If you want, you can use your own state list drawable instead.